# Código google-analytics para monitorar a quantidade de downloads

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

Preciso inserir um código do google-analytics para monitorar quantas vezes um arquivo (um vídeo) foi baixado. Mas como é um link da sidebar que é gerado de forma dinâmica, não tenho como inserir direto no código.

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link','click', 'Download clicado');"
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, tive que gerar um código jquery que pegasse a referência do elemento; depois eu apenas disse para ele aplicar a seguinte função:

```html
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   jQuery('.portfolio-side .panel:eq(2) a:eq(2)').click(function(){
      ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'click', jQuery(this).text()); 
   });
});
</script>
```